# Slicing Time in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I'm reading two db columns into pandas dataframe. It works fine but time data on Db is like this "2018-01-18T00:00:00". I just need to slice the year,month and day. I don't need time since its all 00:00 in db. How do we slice it? Thank you!

```
tables_prices='''SELECT date, tryprice FROM Price'''

df=pd.read_sql_query(tables_prices, conn)    
x=df['date']   
y=df['tryprice']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `to_datetime`

```
df
Out[254]: 
                  date
0  2018-01-18T00:00:00
1  2018-01-18T00:00:00
2  2018-01-18T00:00:00
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.date
df
Out[256]: 
         date
0  2018-01-18
1  2018-01-18
2  2018-01-18

#year: pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.year
#Month: pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.month
#day:pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.day
```